# Ruby - get constants from arbitrary classes / modules

Tags: ruby

I have two classes:

```
class Ios 
  REST_ENDPOINT = 'http://rest'
  SOAP_ENDPOINT = 'http://soap'
end

class Android
  REST_ENDPOINT = 'http://rest'
  SOAP_ENDPOINT = 'http://soap'
end
```

Then I have two classes for REST and SOAP:

```
class REST
  def some_action
    # I want to use the endpoint based on device type
  end
end


class SOAP
  def some_action
    # I want to use the endpoint based on device type 
  end
end
```

How can I use the end_point URLs based on device type in REST and SOAP classes?

Regards,
Kayen

Comment: What you have is not valid Rudy code. Your title also appears to have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: As @AndrewMarshall said, this is invalid code for many reasons. I can't see how someone could upvote this question. You should first study at least the basics of Ruby and better construct your question. Title is also misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this something you are trying to achieve?

```
class REST
  def some_action
    ios_url = URI.parse("#{Ios::REST_ENDPOINT}/login")
    android_url = URI.parse("#{Android::REST_ENDPOINT}/login")
  end
end

class SOAP
  def some_action
    ios_url = URI.parse("#{Ios::SOAP_ENDPOINT}/login")
    android_url = URI.parse("#{Android::SOAP_ENDPOINT}/login")
  end
end
```

you could also use some refactoring like this:

#### Mixin

```
module Endpoints

  def initialize device = Ios
    @device = device_class(device)
  end

  def url device = nil
    URI.parse "#{endpoint(device || @device)}/login"
  end

  def ios_url
    URI.parse "#{endpoint Ios}/login"
  end

  def android_url
    URI.parse "#{endpoint Android}/login"
  end

  private
  def endpoint device
    device_class(device).const_get self.class.name + '_ENDPOINT'
  end

  def device_class device
    device.is_a?(Class) ? 
      device : 
      Object.const_get(device.to_s.capitalize)
  end

end
```

#### Include Mixin in your classes

```
class REST
  include Endpoints

  def some_action
    # use ios_url and android_url here
  end
end

class SOAP
  include Endpoints

  def some_action
    # use ios_url and android_url here
  end
end
```

#### Some Testing:

```
puts REST.new(:Ios).url
#=> http://ios-rest.com/login

puts REST.new.url :Ios
#=> http://ios-rest.com/login

puts REST.new.ios_url
#=> http://ios-rest.com/login


puts REST.new(:Android).url
#=> http://android-rest.com/login

puts REST.new.url :Android
#=> http://android-rest.com/login

puts SOAP.new.android_url
#=> http://android-soap.com/login
```

#### [Here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=ruby-classes-or-modules.rb&versions=1.9.3&run=true) is a working demo

Comment: Sorry, let me put this in a better way: 

`Class Rest

url = URI.parse("#{REST_ENDPOINT}/login")

end`

I want to get REST_ENDPOINT from the device classes Ios and Android classes as mentioned above.

Comment: then you simply do like this: `URI.parse("#{Ios::REST_ENDPOINT}/login")` and `URI.parse("#{Android::REST_ENDPOINT}/login")`

Comment: it works!!! Was wondering whether Ios/Android can be paramaterised like URI.parse("#{Device::REST_ENDPOINT}/login"). How can I pass this from my cucumber test Given /^I am using is (.*) device$/ do |device|#pending end

Comment: try `do |device| ... URI.parse("#{device.const_get :REST_ENDPOINT}/login")`

Comment: or `do |device| ...  URI.parse("#{Object.const_get(device)::REST_ENDPOINT}/login")`

Comment: awesome!! the second one works!!! At the moment I have to use a global variable $device for this to be visible to REST Class, is there a way around it?

Comment: create a instance of `REST` class for each use case: `REST.new(device).url`. see updated answer

Comment: or like this: `REST.new.url device`